# Background won't fill the screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create a login screen, but I can't find a way to make the background fill the whole screen. When I apply a color to the background it only reaches the last view I put on the screen.

I've tried to put `style = {{flex : 1}}` on KeyboardAvoidingView parents and tried to wrap the layout in a `<View style={{flex: 1}} >` too.

It seems to be something related to KeyboardAvoidingView or ScrollView, but I'm not sure and I don't know what else I can do.

[image: Here is a picture of what is happening.]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome, Zocial } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import SubmitButton from "../../shared/SubmitButton";
import FocusAwareStatusBar from "../../shared/StatusBar";
import SelectionButton from "../../shared/SelectionButton";

import { loginFirebase } from "../../db/AuthUser";
//import { firebase } from "./Firebase";
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    flex: 1,
  },

  loginform: {
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    marginTop: 64,
  },

  inputs: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto_400Regular",
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#000",
    borderBottomColor: "#dcdcdc",
    borderBottomWidth: 0.8,
    paddingBottom: 8,
    paddingLeft: 12,
  },

  loginSocialNetworkContainer: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    elevation: 6,
    borderRadius: 6,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },

  loginSocialNetwork: {
    alignContent: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 232,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 2,
  },

  loginSocialNetworkText: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontFamily: "Roboto_400Regular",
    color: "#f7f7f7",
  },
});

export default function Login({ navigation }) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <FocusAwareStatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#88c9bf" />
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} >
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.background}>
          <View style={styles.loginform}>
            <TextInput
              style={{ ...styles.inputs, marginBottom: 20 }}
              placeholder="Nome de usuário"
              autoCorrect={false}
              onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}
              value={email}
            />

            <TextInput
              style={{ ...styles.inputs, marginBottom: 52 }}
              placeholder="Senha"
              autoCorrect={false}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              onChangeText={(password) => setPassword(password)}
              value={password}
            />
          </View>

          <SubmitButton
            text="ENTRAR"
            onPress={() => {
              loginFirebase(email, password);
            }}
          />

          {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { loginFirebase(email, password) }}>
            <Text>Press Here</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity> */}

          <View
            style={{ ...styles.loginSocialNetworkContainer, marginTop: 72 }}
          >
            <FontAwesome.Button
              name="facebook-square"
              style={styles.loginSocialNetwork}
              size={17.5}
              iconStyle={{ color: "#f7f7f7" }}
              backgroundColor="#194f7c"
              onPress={() => {}}
            >
              <Text style={styles.loginSocialNetworkText}>
                ENTRAR COM FACEBOOK
              </Text>
            </FontAwesome.Button>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.loginSocialNetworkContainer}>
            <Zocial.Button
              name="googleplus"
              style={styles.loginSocialNetwork}
              size={15}
              iconStyle={{
                color: "#f7f7f7",
                marginRight: 9.3,
                marginLeft: 0.3,
              }}
              backgroundColor="#f25f5c"
              onPress={() => {}}
            >
              <Text
                style={{ ...styles.loginSocialNetworkText, paddingRight: 14 }}
              >
                ENTRAR COM GOOGLE
              </Text>
            </Zocial.Button>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill your background screen by using `height: 100vh` in your background styling. `vh` covers the whole screen irrespective of the screen height.

```
  background: {
    backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    flex: 1,
    height: 100vh
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the:

```
contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
```

It wraps your content in an inner component.

Comment: It wraps your content in an inner component, I guess that's why it's called `contentContainerStyle`

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex: 1` in your Parent View Style, flex will define how your items are going to “fill” over the available space along your main axis. Space will be divided according to each element's flex property. Jus't see in official docs in this link https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox